# AND operator in regex doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to be able to match those values.

1. not 0 8 times
2. not 0 11 times

AND

1. 0-9 8 times
2. 0-9 11 times

It seem there is no AND operators i tried this..

```
^(?=[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{11})(?=[^0]{8}|[^0]{11})$
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you add an example of a use case you are trying to do?

Comment: A _AND_ operator could be construed as a construct called assertions. They evaluate a sub-expression without moving the match position. Example: given string "1", the regex for _NOT_ 0, _AND_ 0 to 9, is - `^(?=[^0])(?=[0-9])`. Which is otherwise economically written as `^[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^(?!0{8}$)(?!0{11}$)(?:\d{8}|\d{11})$
```

Online explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/sH1nZ5

Alternatively, you could use

```
^(?!0{8}$)(?!0{11}$)\d{8}(?:\d{3})?$
```

which does the exact same thing: http://regex101.com/r/iX2xM2

Comment: Amazing! So its : instead of =. Where does this : come from ? Its is the equivalent in .NET ? I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: @Rushino `(?:...)` is actually a _non-capturing group_. It is used when you want to group part of the regex, but don't need to capture it for later backreferencing.

Comment: Yes it do! Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [union of two sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) and the OR `|` operator if you want to match both sets.

```
^(?=[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{11})|(?=[^0]{8}|[^0]{11})$
```

If you simply want to match a string that is not `0` 8 or 11 times, followed by `0-9` 8 or 11 times, just put them in order.

Comment: How? I am already using OR for matching 8 numbers or 11 but there is an AND too to exclude 8 numbers = 0 and 11 numbers = 0.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. If you're looking for the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of two sets, you just have to find the intersection of your requirements, which, in this case, is just `[1-9]{8}|[1-9]{11}`, as `^0 & 0-9 = 1-9`

Comment: @Michael Tang - +1 For comment.

Answer (score 0):

Or, it could be written this way

```
 # ^(?=.{8}(?:.{3})?$)[1-9]+$

 ^ 
 (?=
      .{8} 
      (?: .{3} )?
      $ 
 )
 [1-9]+ 
 $
```